# Including a PHP file muliple times which has jquery script inside it, script doesn't run at each instance

Tags: php, jquery, loops, include

I have a php file which is required many times, includes a small jquery snippet that is supposed to run at each instance the php file is included. However seems like jquery runs all at once in the end because I am getting variables value at once instead of at each instance. So my php file that includes another php file number of times is
`base-features.php`

```
<?php 

  $youtubelinks = array(
      '0' => 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/NilASeqRsjw'
      '1' => 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/eXG8PbwmUJw'
  );

  foreach($youtubelinks as $key => $val) {
     $ytlink = $val; 
     require('youtubelink.php');

  }
```

On my `youtubelink.php` I can see the `$ytlink` variable

```
  <div id="page-corporate-video-overlay" class="page-corporate-video-overlay">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row block">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <?php print $ytlink ?>
                <p><span class="video-play-icon"></span><p>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
 <div class="page-corporate-video">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="inner">
                   <iframe id="corporate-video" class="page-corporate-video-iframe" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>


 <!--The jquery script I am having problem with-->
 <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var videoYoutube = "<?php print $ytlink; ?>"

    $('.page-corporate-video-overlay').click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).closest("div.page-corporate-video-overlay").offset().top-15
        }, 500);

        $(this).hide();

        console.log(videoYoutube);
        $(this).closest('div.base-feature').css({'background-image':'none','height':'auto'});
        $(this).next('div.page-corporate-video').find('.page-corporate-video-iframe').attr('src',videoYoutube+"?controls=0&rel=0&showinfo=0&enablejsapi=1&autoplay=1&modestbranding=1&theme=light");
        $(this).next('div.page-corporate-video').show();
    });
});
```

So when I click on `.page-corporate-video-overlay', I get two values of the`videoYoutube` variable. This is causing me problems to embed the right video onto the iframe as only last value gets embedded instead of each iframe getting relative youtube variable value during the each loop instance.

Comment: This bit `$('.page-corporate-video-overlay')` loops through *all* of the `.page-corporate-video-overlay` divs each time.  So only the last one will be remain as the previous ones have been overwritten.

Comment: Consider a refactor - put `$ytlink` as a `data-ytlink` on the `.page-corporate-video` div, then have a single jquery doc ready method (not the same one per link) that reads `videoYoutube` from the data attribute.

Comment: @freedomn-m Thank you for your prompt response and very helpful refactoring suggestion. I did exactly as you said and I made it work. I am going to post an answer based on your refactoring suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @freedomn-m 's comment I refactored my code according to his suggestion.

Refactored `youtubelink.php`

Everything is almost the same except I added an extra attribute on the `div.page-corporate-video-overlay` of `data-ytlink ="<?php print $ytlink;?>"` and on my Jquery within my click function event I added

```
 var videoYoutube = $(this).attr('data-ytlink');
```

Now I am able to embed videos correctly.